# Transfer Users between Organizations in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have 17 different organizations of Dynamics CRM 2011. I want to create a user in one of them and then export/import that user to the remaining 16 organizations. I tried to use XRMToolBox, but i do not see an option for user transfer. Please assist.

Comment: You can Import them with Excel ;)

Comment: Please guide me

Comment: I didn't found official dokumentation for CRM 2011 but here is similar question with how to steps :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272917/how-to-import-users-in-crm-2011-with-source-guid